# Internal Server Error

Tags: magento2, php, database, magento2.3.4

I just hosted on Godaddy, and i downleded magento 2.3.6 from magento official site and i uploaded it into filemanager, when i run the URL, it is showing 500 error.
Can you please guys help me this.

````
The server encountered an internal error or misconfiguration and was unable to complete your request.

Please contact the server administrator at webmaster@towercirclestore.com to inform them of the time this error occurred, and the actions you performed just before this error.

More information about this error may be available in the server error log.

Additionally, a 500 Internal Server Error error was encountered while trying to use an ErrorDocument to handle the request.```
````

Comment: there is any problem in .htaccess of your root directory. do you have server configurations the same as Magento requirements? this usually occurs when any of the apache modules like `mod_rewrite` or `mod_version` is missing

Comment: yes, there is .htaccess is present in the root directory.

Comment: please check `mod_rewrite` and `mod_version` are isntalled on your server

Comment: both are apache modules

Comment: Can you please tell me, how to check mod_rewrite and mod_versions ?

Comment: login to the server using terminal and run `apache2ctl -M` in the terminal you will get all installed modules on your server I am working on ubuntu and is working fine if you are using another server please find an alternative of this command

Comment: 923445790784 here it is

Comment: Can you please tell me ur num? above num have 12 digits

Comment: i am from pakistan add country code with 03445790784

Comment: mod_rewrite is activated

Comment: still, it's not opening

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/116180/discussion-between-waqar-ali-and-nikhil-gantyala).